# How to save email from outlook using python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I am trying to save email from sub-folder using the below python script, I am trying to restrict with `days=1` means I only need to save emails which are 1 day old.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from datetime import date, timedelta
import datetime as dt


msg_location = r'C:\Users\rahul\Desktop\msg_files'



outlook = Dispatch("outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders['Email_snapper']

messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
Body_content = message.Body
print(Body_content)


for msg in messages:
    lastWeekDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1)
    lastWeekDateTime = lastWeekDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
    message = messages.Ryestrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastWeekDateTime + "'")
    #name = str(message)
message.SaveAs(msg+".msg")
```

Comment: i used it to save the email

Comment: File "C:\Users\RahulPycharmProjects\pythonProject3\Testing email.py", line 24, in <module>
    message.SaveAs(msg+".msg")
  File "C:\Users\Rahull\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 511, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Restrict.SaveAs

Comment: i would like to name it with subject line + the date it is received on

Comment: i just posted in comments section

Answer (score 1):

*Try setting your **filter** like the following*

*Example*

```
import re

import win32com.client
import datetime as dt
import os

Outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
olNs = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6)

lastWeekDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1)
lastWeekDateTime = lastWeekDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
print(lastWeekDateTime)

Filter = ("@SQL=" + chr(34) + "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" +
          chr(34) + " >= '" + lastWeekDateTime + "'")

Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
Items.Sort('[ReceivedTime]', False)

for Item in Items:
    print(Item.Subject)
    print(Item.ReceivedTime)
    save_name = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', str(Item.Subject)) + '.msg'
    Item.SaveAs(os.getcwd() + '//' + save_name)
else:
    print("No Item")
```

Comment: thanks for this 0m3r, what's the use of @sql here ?

Comment: and in case i need to add a subfolder, can i use something like inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders['sub_folder_name']

Comment: Also, is there a way to save those mails to a local folder ? like all the emails present in sub folder with filter time as today

Comment: @RahulVaidya, answer updated to save mails

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is `Restrict`, not `Ryestrict`.

Secondly, `Restrict` returns `Items` collection, not a single item. You need to iterate over the items in that collection. If you only expect a single item, use `Find` instead of `Restrict`.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for the suggestions, now it is failing on the last line (message.SaveAs(msg+".msg")

Comment: i am trying to save all the emails from sub-folder with subjectline + received time

Comment: `SaveAs` takes **fully qualified** file name. e.g. `c:\temp\mymessage.msg`. Secondly, `msg` is an object, not a string, so you end up with the default string property, which is `Subject`. And subject can contain invalid (for a file name) characters (e.g. `:`). You need to clean up the file name first.

Comment: can you please help me with the correct line of code ?

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: i am not able to get where exactly i need to make changes to make it run?

Comment: You need to do two things - specify a fully qualified (path + file name) argument to `SaveAs` and make sure it does not have any invalid characters. Mind you, I do not use Python.